# read email form the gmail using imap in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, email

I want to read the email from gmail using imap with servlet and jsp.
But i could not do that.I get in the simple Java class. But when I try this code into jsp and servlet both are given error.
I used following code.

> try{
>           java.util.Properties properties = System.getProperties();
>         properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
>         javax.mail.Session s = javax.mail.Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null);
>       //create session instance
>       System.out.println("Connected");
>       javax.mail.Store store = s.getStore("imaps");//create store instance
>       store.connect("pop.gmail.com", "studentusecmp@gmail.com", "##########");
>       //set your user_name and password
>       System.out.println(store);
>       Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
>       //set folder from where u wants to read mails
>       inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);//set access type of Inbox
>       Message messages[] = inbox.getMessages();// gets inbox messages
>       for (int i = 0; i 
>   System.out.println("From : " + messages[i].getFrom()[0]); //print
>   email id of sender      System.out.println("Sub : " +
>   messages[i].getSubject()); //print subject of email
>   System.out.println("Receive Date:"+messages[i].getReceivedDate());
>   System.out.println("Description:"+messages[i].getDescription());
>       }catch(Exception e)   {    e.printStackTrace();     }

and Error

> Stacktrace:   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)   at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)    at
>   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:399)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:317)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:204)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:182)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:311)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

which were i did mistack?Please help me.
Thanks.
-chintan

Comment: Two pieces of advice - 1. Please wrap your code in the right tag. It is difficult to salvage it at this point. 2 - If this code is run from a JSP, please do everyone a favor and move it to a service component. At the moment it appears the code would not even compile. `javacError`

Comment: I wrap my code with script-let tag. It cause any effect?

Comment: You should not post passwords while posting a question.

Comment: Thanks. I just forgot.I will be careful next time. Thanks once again.@Sao

Comment: @chintan please do the right thing and change your password now. The fact that it is not visible here now does not mean that isn't in the database anymore.

Comment: Is there any other way to read mail from gmail using jsp/servlet? plz tell me.

Comment: @Deepak You are right. This code isnot actullu compile,because of missing jar file in the webconten/lib folder. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I got the answer after some googling. and check the code step by step. It can not find the jar file in the /WebContent/lib/  Folder. I put it manually. It work fine.